# Tibble select word and add column

Tags: r, tidyr

I have a list of word and phrases and I would like create a DB that select that word and add in a column, not delete but add. This is how I want do, how can I do?

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
```

|      Heading 1      |
|---------------------|
|   Hello world       |
|            Say world|
|        Say something|
tibble(
"Hello world",
"Say world",
"Say something"
)

```
list_of_words <- tolower(c("world","something"))
```

| Heading 1 | Heading 2 |
| --- | --- |
| Hello world | world |
| Say world | world |
| Say something | something |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `regmatches` like this:

```r
DB <- data.frame(heading_1 = c("Hello world", "Say world", "Say something"))
DB
#>       heading_1
#> 1   Hello world
#> 2     Say world
#> 3 Say something
list_of_words <- tolower(c("world","something"))
words <- paste(list_of_words, collapse="|")
DB$heading_2 <- unlist(regmatches(DB$heading_1, gregexpr(words, DB$heading_1)))
DB
#>       heading_1 heading_2
#> 1   Hello world     world
#> 2     Say world     world
#> 3 Say something something
```

<sup>Created on 2022-07-21 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: words <- paste(list_of_words, collapse="|") can you explain what do?

Comment: @Inuraghe, That is for the pattern argument of gregexpr so that the function knows which words it should extract, and you use | for that to let the function know what the words are.